# Is there a transgression on this tzitzit tying?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, techeles

Suppose someone bought some tkhelet for his tallis, wanting to tie the Rambam tzitzit, which requires 1 half tkhelet/half white string and 3 white strings, so once it goes through the hole of the corner of the tallis it turns into 8 strings, one of them tkhelet and 7 white ones.

Subsequently, he realizes he had gotten FULL tkhelet strings, meaning he'd gotten 6 white strings and 2 tkhelet.

The question is: Can one still tie the Rambam tzitzit? Would it be a transgression? Would it be better to just accept the fact that he should tie his tzitzit in a different way?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. One of the things this site doesn't do is provide personalized halachic advice which is why this question was put on-hold. You can edit it to depersonalize it and (e.g.,) ask if one can tie a Rambam tzitzit with x strings. Hope to see you around!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why isn't he just getting new correct strings? Is the issue that he needs to wear a garment in the meantime and these are the only strings he has available? That's quite a far-fetched case, but ok

Comment: I think an interesting question would be, could you cut a techeiles string and a white string in half and tie them together, making a half-blue half-white string according to the Rambam's shittah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Probably because he doesn't want to spend money on a new set if he already has one.

Comment: @alex he doesn't have a correct one though... whether or not you can Bedieved tie it and wear it, it's still wrong. like I said, is the case just about wearing something in the meantime till you can get correct strings?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think he's asking if he can lechatchila tie it now that he bedieved bought it.

Comment: @alex you mean Lechatkhila until he gets new ones? I don't understand how anyone could even ask if having wrong strings could ever be thought of as done. It's wrong. Just like all white or all blue is wrong. The Mitzva is to get X white and Y blue strings. What is there to even wonder about other than temporary permissions if the right number aren't available? Is the $40 to get correct strings more than a fifth of his net worth?

Comment: @DoubleAA The strings are not wrong b'etzem. It's just not the Rambam's position. I imagine he's asking whether it is okay to follow the Ra'avad's view on number of strings instead of the Rambam's view, and/or whether he can/should still use the Rambam's method of tying if he's using the Ra'avad's number of strings. (Granted he should perhaps clarify precisely what his question is.)

Comment: @alex isn't his whole premise that the person holds like the Rambam? If he wants to Paskin like a different rishon he should just ask his rabbi which rishon he holds like. We can't answer if he holds like someone else. Obviously if he holds like tosfot then he should buy and tie like tosfot. If he holds like some combination he should buy and tie like that. That wasn't the question

Comment: @DoubleAA We don't know to what extent his "ruling" was to follow Rambam.It might have been a definitive ruling, or it might have just been "heck, it's a machlokes rishonim, we don't know what to do, let's follow Rambam as the default". Now that his situation has changed, he is wondering whether following Rambam is really that important, if there are other opinions in the rishonim he would be following. I think it's a valid conceptual question to ask how the different shittos in number of techelet strings relate to the different shittos in how to tie, and to what extent they are meakev. >cont.

Comment: <cont. @DoubleAA though he should clarify that this is what he is asking (if it is) and edit it so it is not asking for a ruling, nor premised on any rulings he has received.

Comment: @alex what your presenting is a possible real life situation which we aren't capable of handling at mi yodeya. Too many possibilities. The person should just ask his rabbi why he got the psak that he got. We can't tell him. As is this question isn't a good fit for our site even if phrased in the third person because it doesn't clearly explain the basis of the case. I'll close as unclear if it get reopened

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree. But I do think there is a good underlying conceptual question here, which if edited for clarification and depersonalization, would be worthy of reopening.

Comment: Just to note ,the Rambam may be the only shittah where if there are non white strings besides the techeiles may pasul the tzizts. So having extra techeleis may be a problem.

Comment: @Sam Rashi and Ra'avad both seem to explain that that would be not in fulfillment of "min knaf" (and presumably invalid).